# Wildcards in SQL parameter

Tags: sql, parameters, wildcard, sql-like

I need to do a like search, in my SQL Server database. BUT, how do I do this, while still using parameters for my search value?

I am not talking about encapsulating in `%`'s. I need to be able to add a `%` in the middle of the search word.

```
WHERE title LIKE '%foo%bar%'
```

as an example, but with params.

Edit:
To elaborate on the params:
I am using MS SQL 2008, and C#, so it would be:

```
WHERE title LIKE '@SearchParam'
```

and `@SearchParam` would then be set to `"%foo%bar%"`.

I hope that makes sense?

Comment: This sounds like an invitation to sql injection.  Perhaps you should look a full text index instead?

Comment: can you give an example of the parameter? I'm guessing that you are passing the parameter as `foobar` and want to insert the `%` in between. Am I right?

Comment: I simply want to allow the user to add a * in his search field, and then replace it with %. So the user could search for "Nic*olai" and get "Nicoolai" back. I am trying to avoid opening for injections. If I cannot do this with parameters, I probably won't do it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine

```
create proc dbo.lookupWild(@LIKEclause VARCHAR(20))
as
begin
    select * from teams where Name like @LIKEclause
end
go
exec lookupWild 'E%G%'
```

And things like    '1=1 -- drop table' are not SQL injected, they are just part of the wildcard search

Comment: Is stored procedures really the only way to do this?

Comment: I don't really understand how this would work? If you: exec lookupWild 'E%' or '1'='1 - Why will that not break the exec command?

Comment: Give it a try.  SQL does not interpret the parameter as additional text for the query.   The parameter is only the LIKE clause, so if you put in your example, SQL views it as a LIKE expression....

Comment: You don't have to do it as a stored procedure, the above code will work on any select statement.    SQL injection becomes an issue when you take the INPUT string and combine it with another string, then run EXEC or SP_ExecSQL using the string you built as a parameter.

Comment: You are right, it works. I just don't understand it. I would assume the wildcards would be escaped and not be considered wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine if you are using Stored Procedures. [Here](http://www.sqlmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/ms-sql-server/13377/Accepting-wildcards-like-in-input-parameters-of-stored-procedures) is a similar thread.

[How to Escape Wildcard Characters While Searching in SQL Server](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-Escape-Wildcard-Characters-While-Searching-in-SQL-Server--873.php)

Are you looking for something like below?

```
where title like '%foo[%]bar%'
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm understanding the question wrong, but I don't think a stored procedure will fix the underlying issue here.